# VLOOKUP accross several columns in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to lookup data in one sheet and find it in another sheet and then display a column value IF the other elements in the next columns match, b/c some of the numbers repeat.  here's an example.  Thanks for the help.

Sheet One

```
Column G (DocNum)     H (Date)      I (Amount)        J (Action)

    00381959           20140221     $247.25      
    00381959           20140221     $5000.00  
    00381959           20130930     $25.56   
    00321201           20130815     $15000.00  
    00740022           20121212     $1525.00
```

Sheet two (thousands of DocNums) has the Action plan needed to be populated onto Sheet One.

Sheet Two

```
Column F (DocNum)     G (Date)       H (Amount)    I (Action)

    00381959           20140221     $247.25       Explanation 1  
    00381959           20140221     $5000.00      Explanation 2   
    00381959           20130930     $25.56        Explanation 3  
    00321201           20130815     $15000.00     Explanation 4  
    00740022           20121212     $1525.00      Explanation 5
```

So im thinking a formula to match the words:  Look up Sheet One G:G in Sheet 2 F:I and if there compare sheet one G, H, I = sheet two F, G, H, then I (meaning fill in the explanation from sheet 2 onto sheet one).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "key" column, like in column A :

```
sheet Two
A2 = F2&G2&H2
```

then do your VLOOKUP to find the key :

```
Sheet One
J2=vlookup(G2&H2&I2;Two!A:I;9;false)
```

Easy to read, easy to check your key is/isn't defined, easy to maintain !

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in sheet one `J2`:

```
=INDEX(Two!I:I,MATCH(G2 & H2 & I2,Two!F:F & Two!G:G & Two!H:H,0))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag it down.

To make formula faster, I suggest you to use exact ranges:

```
=INDEX(Two!$I$1:$I$100,MATCH(G2 & H2 & I2,Two!$F$1:$F$100 & Two!$G$1:$G$100 & Two!$H$1:$H$100,0))
```

Comment: Hi Simoco - When i tried your formula with the INDEX, it returns a #Value! answer.  Any ideas?  thanks.

Comment: have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead just ENTER to evaluate formula?